# Heroku not migrating with new fields

Tags: python, django, heroku, django-models, django-migrations

I have been working on my local machine and I recently added some field to an existant model.

I tried to push it this morning on Heroku and make the migrations and this is the message I get :
[image]

My models.py

```
Class Todo(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE,verbose_name="Nom de l'utilisateur")
    text = models.CharField(max_length=150, verbose_name="Nom de la Todo")
    content = models.TextField(verbose_name="Description supplémentaire",null=True, blank=True)
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    complete = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    recurrence = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    urgence = models.BooleanField(default=False,verbose_name="Tâche urgente")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.text
def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse('dashboard-home')
```

Todo.reccurence is the new field.

Traceback :

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: 

Django Version: 2.1.7
Python Version: 3.6.7
Installed Applications:
['blog.apps.BlogConfig',
 'dashboard.apps.DashboardConfig',
 'users.apps.UsersConfig',
 'crispy_forms',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'storages',
 'cloudinary']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']


Template error:
In template /app/blog/templates/blog/base.html, error at line 0
   column dashboard_todo.recurrence does not exist
LINE 1: ...todo"."date_posted", "dashboard_todo"."complete", "dashboard...
                                                             ^

   1 : {% load crispy_forms_tags %}
   2 : <!DOCTYPE html>
   3 : <html>
   4 : <head>
   5 : 
   6 :   <!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics -->
   7 : <script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-134278636-1"></script>
   8 : <script>
   9 :   window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
   10 :   function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}


Traceback:

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py" in _execute
  85.                 return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)

The above exception (column dashboard_todo.recurrence does not exist
LINE 1: ...todo"."date_posted", "dashboard_todo"."complete", "dashboard...
                                                             ^
) was the direct cause of the following exception:

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
  34.             response = get_response(request)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  156.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  154.                 response = response.render()

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/response.py" in render
  106.             self.content = self.rendered_content

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/response.py" in rendered_content
  83.         content = template.render(context, self._request)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py" in render
  61.             return self.template.render(context)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  171.                     return self._render(context)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in _render
  163.         return self.nodelist.render(context)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  937.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render_annotated
  904.             return self.render(context)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py" in render
  150.             return compiled_parent._render(context)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in _render
  163.         return self.nodelist.render(context)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  937.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render_annotated
  904.             return self.render(context)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py" in render
  62.                 result = block.nodelist.render(context)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  937.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render_annotated
  904.             return self.render(context)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py" in render
  166.             len_values = len(values)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in __len__
  250.         self._fetch_all()

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in _fetch_all
  1186.             self._result_cache = list(self._iterable_class(self))

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in __iter__
  54.         results = compiler.execute_sql(chunked_fetch=self.chunked_fetch, chunk_size=self.chunk_size)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py" in execute_sql
  1065.             cursor.execute(sql, params)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py" in execute
  100.             return super().execute(sql, params)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py" in execute
  68.         return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py" in _execute_with_wrappers
  77.         return executor(sql, params, many, context)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py" in _execute
  85.                 return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/utils.py" in __exit__
  89.                 raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py" in _execute
  85.                 return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)

Exception Type: ProgrammingError at /
Exception Value: column dashboard_todo.recurrence does not exist
LINE 1: ...todo"."date_posted", "dashboard_todo"."complete", "dashboard...
                                                             ^
```

What I usually do is deleting database on my local machine and run migrate again but I really can't do that with real data.

Thanks

Comment: "What I usually do is deleting database on my local machine and run migrate again but I really can't do that with real data."—well you probably shouldn't be doing this regularly in development, either. It's important that your migrations work properly from the previous state of the database. Did you make sure to commit the new migration? Were you careful not to remove or modify any old migrations?

Comment: Did you found answer for this question.I also have the same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not be running makemigrations on Heroku. Do it locally, commit the result, then run migrate on Heroku.

Comment: Actually I did it, everything work fined until I push the project to Heroku. When I saw the error I tried a makemigrations and migrate

Comment: Please post the full traceback (click the "Switch to copy-and-paste view") in the question, as text.